# EF Code First - id being mapped as FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Say I have an Article and a FeatureArticle, where a FeatureArticle points to the Article itself, an Order, and it's own Id. Right now EF is simply setting the Id to that of the Article. For whatever reason that then means I can't add multiple FeatureArticles (point to different articles).

The configuration are as follows:

```
public sealed class FeatureArticleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FeatureArticle>
{
    public FeatureArticleMap()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.Id);
        Property(o => o.Order).IsRequired();
        HasRequired(o => o.Article).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}

public sealed class ArticleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.Id);

        Property(o => o.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        Property(o => o.Content).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Then EF is writing entries like (the id is 5 to demonstrate the point):

```
Article:
Id: 5, Name: "Some Article", Content: "Blah"
FeatureArticle:
Id: 5, Order: 0, ArticleId: 0
```

Where I expected the ArticleId to be 5. The good thing is EF is returning back what I expect, but then it's broken because I can't add more than one FeatureArticle, and I suspect it's to do with the way it's mapping that Id.

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases with my tables there is a separate FK-ID in the tables and the FK definition is different. I don't know if this FK definition shown below matches your needs.

Combined with your code it would look like
 
Models:

```
public partial class FeatureArticle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}

public partial class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        this.FeatureArticles = new List<FeatureArticle>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FeatureArticle> FeatureArticles { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public sealed class FeatureArticleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FeatureArticle>
{
    public FeatureArticleMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(o => o.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(o => o.Order).IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("FeatureArticle");
        Property(o => o.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(o => o.Order).HasColumnName("Order");
        Property(o => o.ArticleId).HasColumnName("ArticleId");

        // Relationships
        HasRequired(o => o.Article)
            .WithMany(o => o.FeatureArticles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ArticleId);
    }
}

public sealed class ArticleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(o => o.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(o => o.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        Property(o => o.Content).IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Article");
        Property(o => o.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        Property(o => o.Content).HasColumnName("Content");
    }
}
```

I need to mention that this FK constraint that I am using in my tables was modelled with the EF designer and then converted with [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to code first.